# why is my vue-router not rendering my files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I tried to use the Vue-router in my Vue project.
I installed it with `npm install vue-router@latest`.
My problem right now is, that it isn`t working

My router.js file looks like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Home from './src/components/Home.vue'

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home 
    },
  ],
});
```

then I want to import it into the App.vue file with the `<router-view></router-view>`tag, but here is the whole file:

```vue
<script setup>
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router';
</script>

<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

Here is also a picture from the file structure:

[image]

Home.vue is just the whole landingpage, but when I run the server with `npm run dev`, it just shows a white page. Does someone know what the problem here is?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev it is also not working to be honest

Comment: Consider following the guide until you make it workable, https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript You don't use `new Router` object anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's troubleshoot this step by step:

1. **Check Your Vue and Vue Router Versions**: Ensure that the versions of Vue and Vue Router are compatible. Vue Router 4 is only compatible with Vue 3. If you're using Vue 2, you should install Vue Router 3 instead.
2. **Correct Import in App.vue**: In your `App.vue`, you're using `<script setup>` which is a Vue 3 feature. However, the way you're importing `RouterView` might be incorrect for Vue 3. You should import it directly from 'vue' like this:

   ```js
   <script setup>
   import { RouterView } from 'vue';
   </script>

   <template>
       <RouterView />
   </template>
   ```
3. **Router Installation and Usage**: In your `router.js`, the setup seems correct. However, make sure you are correctly initializing and using the router in your main application file (usually `main.js` or `main.ts`). It should look something like this:

   ```js
   import { createApp } from 'vue';
   import App from './App.vue';
   import router from './router'; // make sure the path is correct

   createApp(App)
     .use(router)
     .mount('#app');
   ```
4. **Check for Console Errors**: When you run the server, check the browser's console for any errors. Console errors can provide valuable information about what might be going wrong.
5. **Router Configuration**: Your router configuration seems fine, but double-check the path to the `Home.vue` component. Make sure the file path is correct and that there are no typos.
6. **Content in Home.vue**: Ensure that your `Home.vue` component is correctly set up and contains visible content. Sometimes, if the component is empty or has display issues, it might seem like the router is not working.
7. **Vue DevTools**: Use Vue DevTools for Chrome or Firefox to inspect the Vue component hierarchy and router states. This can help you identify if the router is correctly set up and if the components are being loaded.

If you've checked all these and the problem persists, the issue might be more specific to your project setup. In that case, reviewing the complete project configuration or any console errors in detail would be necessary to pinpoint the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Was `vue-router` added to the Vue instance in `main.js` like the below?

```
import { createApp } from "vue"
import { router } from "../router" // based on where your router.js is placed

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)
app.mount("#app")
```

Also, your folder structure isn't following the convention. Looks really messy.